# Rename [youtube-streaming] to [youtube-live] (or remove)

Tags: discussion, tags

Reasons:

1. "**YouTube Live**" is the official name of the product (used both in [the HC](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7083786?hl=en), and [in media reports](https://techcrunch.com/2017/04/18/streamers-flock-to-youtube-live-but-the-money-and-crowd-is-still-at-twitch/)).
2. "YouTube Streaming" has a bit of ambiguity as to whether the questioner is talking about streaming in the live sense, or about streaming in the netflix sense.
3. [youtube-streaming](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/youtube-streaming) currently has 4 questions, all of which also contain the [youtube](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/youtube) tag. Given this volume, it may not be worth keeping, but then, I'm coming from a 10k questions per month environment, so my meter may be way off for this community.

Answer (score 5):

1. seems reason enough to me :)

Renaming has been known to cause *massive* issues (on another SE site) so for just four Qs I suggest the mechanism, if to be renamed, be to edit in the new and edit out the old (ie 'manual').

---

This Q reached 40 views with no sign of disagreement and some feint signs of agreement so I have swapped the tags out. [youtube-streaming](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/youtube-streaming) has disappeared and a Usage guide for [youtube-live](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/youtube-live) has been approved, presently:

> This tag should be used to differentiate questions about the streaming service from other questions on this site. Use when the topic is YouTube Live, a service that provides live streams such as of gaming, music, sports and news. This tag may be used in conjunction with tag [youtube].

Comment: I agree, for four questions, it's not a big deal to just swap the tag out.

Comment: Not a bad idea.  I think there's enough evidence for this one, though.

Comment: Why remove youtube?

Comment: "Google" is not a product.  YouTube is an actual product upon which YouTube Live lives.  I understand what you are saying, but I think you are overthinking this.

Comment: Please understand, I'm not handing down anything. :)  I'm just expressing my opinion.  It's easy to say "Well, SE *wants* this", when, in reality, many of these "wants" are *de facto* standards more than anything.