# Rename [youtube-creator-studio]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-synonyms

Many years ago (before I started using it, apparently), it was called [youtube-creator-studio](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/youtube-creator-studio), but it's since been [rebranded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouTube_Studio) to [youtube-studio](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/youtube-studio). The former should therefore be a synonym of the latter. If we really want to be thorough, [studio.youtube.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/studio.youtube.com) (the URL) would be another good synonym.

[image: Google search results showing "YouTube Studio" as the name]

Comment: Related: [Please rename \[youtube-creatorstudio\] to \[youtube-creator-studio\]](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4472/88163), [Rename \[youtube-streaming\] to \[youtube-live\] (or remove)](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4246/88163)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[youtube-creator-studio](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/youtube-creator-studio) is now a synonym for [youtube-studio](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/youtube-studio).

The name was changed by Google in late 2019 and the tag now accurately reflects that.

Thank you for your original suggestion and following up!

Answer (score 1):

Making [youtube-creator-studio](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/youtube-creator-studio) a synonym of [youtube-studio](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/youtube-studio) sounds good to me. ~66% of tags have 20 questions or fewer, so it wouldn't be an outlier.

Answer (score -3):

I wonder if it might be better to make [youtube-creator-studio](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/youtube-creator-studio) a synonym of [youtube](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/youtube). The first, was created almost 6 years ago, it only has 20 questions, 35% are unanswered, and all are tagged [youtube](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/youtube), nobody has got a score of 100 and has posted 20 answers, required to earn the tag bronze badge.

Yesterday, I approved an edit suggestion for the [youtube-creator-studio](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/youtube-creator-studio). It looks to me that the tag wiki still needs work.

It's worth noting that nowadays, Stack Exchange has [Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/). From their tour

> **Video Production Stack Exchange** is a question and answer site for videographers, producers, editors, and enthusiasts spanning the fields of video, and media creation. It's built and run *by you* as part of the [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/) network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about video recording and production.

Their [youtube](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/youtube) tag has 229 questions. They don't have a specific tag for YouTube Studio.

Comment: "I wonder if it might be better to make youtube-creator-studio a synonym of youtube". Not a good idea. I rarely watch videos on YouTube so this would bury the questions that I can answer about YT Studio under a lot that I can't about using YouTube as a consumer.